# When does an AWS RDS Snapshot Become "Safe"?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a large MySQL AWS RDS database I perform snapshots on via the AWS console. My snapshots take a while to complete, so my question is:

Am I safe to make destructive changes to the data once the snapshot has begun, safe in the knowledge I can restore back to when I initiated the snapshot once it completes?

Or do I need to wait for it to fully complete to be 100% safe?

Comment: http://superuser.com/